# how we can delete delete files of s3bucket automatically having certain pattern i.e folder names contains run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

how we can delete files of s3bucket automatically having a certain pattern i.e folder names containing run after 180 days?

run01
run02
run03
name01

o/p:  only the first 3 folders containing 'run'  in its name should get deleted after 180 days

- was trying s3 bucket life cycle rule but seems it does not support regex

would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AWS S3` does not support this functionality out of the box. They `do not have any lifecycle policy that would delete or move objects based on the object names`. You can use the AWS CLI to fetch all the files, filter them and then delete the files that match the regex.

You could try this

```
aws s3 rm <your_bucket_name> --exclude "*" --include "run*"
```

Comment: how to add a parameter in the command for deleting files older than n of days i.e 7 days ?